# EventSource listener does not fire on page load in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, server-sent-events

i'm a bit confused about the reason it does not work in Firefox when it works in other(all) browsers.

Initializing EventSource and registering a listener:

```
var output = new EventSource('/subscribe');

output.addEventListener('shell_stream', function(e) {
    $('#shell-output').append(e.data + "<br/>");
}, false);
```

Then on page loading i'm looking through query string and if there is a file and the run action, i'm sending them to server(via ajax) and the server sending back the data to the listener registered above.

Debugged the script a lot.
It does send request and receive valid response, and server for sure sending data to listener.

However, on Firefox, the listener does not react in any way.

Worth to note what the listener works perfect if the user click Run button, which calls exactly the same function which is called on page load if file and run found in query string.

Also, if I fire an `alert()` on page load and user click it, the listener will work!

Here is the live link to try in various browsers:

http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?file=extract-image.rb&run=true

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that your server tries to send the data to the EventSource before the EventSource HTTP request has made a connection to the server?  The code as written looks like the EventSource and the XHR that you're triggering immediately afterward would race, but it really depends on exactly what the server does when it gets that XHR.

Comment: nope, i had same thoughts too. it definitely send request only after it is connected.

Comment: OK, so I just stepped through this.  When the page loads, the browser gets a 136-byte response on the HTTP connection for the event source.  The response has two rpc_stream events: a show on the progress bar, and a hide on the progress bar.  When I click the "Run" button, I get another show for the progress bar, then a 216 byte chunk which has several shell_stream events, then another rpc_stream to hide the progress bar.  So it looks like on original load the server is just not sending the shell_stream events....

Comment: ok, how then it works in other browsers? Also, why if on load i do a simple `alert('something');` and user clicks it, the stream will work without clicking on Run button. It has something to do with user interaction, like stream will work only after user interacting with the page in some way.

Comment: My best guess is that you still have a race somewhere, which is causing your server to send the wrong thing depending on the order of requests it receives.  Which is how it can work in other browsers, as well as if something changes the timing of events here (which an `alert()` will do).  You may be able to test this theory by doing whatever work you're doing during load off a setTimeout instead...

Comment: @BorisZbarsky this makes sense, will try shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Update

moved this to a separate post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159977

---

=== UPDATE ===

forgot/missed that `onopen` is called every N seconds :)

so my file were running forever :)

using a ugly hack for now:

```
initialized = false;
var output = new EventSource( ... );

output.onopen = function() {
  if(initialized) return true;
  initialized = true;

  ...
  invoke_file_runner( ... );
}
```

`initialized` make sure it will run only once.

---

found it!

my code looks like this:

```
var output = new EventSource( ... );
...
invoke_file_runner( ... );
```

the interesting part is that on all browsers connection is already established when `invoke_file_runner` is executed.

except firefox, where connection is established afterward.

no idea how and why.

the fix is simple:

```
var output = new EventSource( ... );
output.onopen = function() {
  ...
  invoke_file_runner( ... );
}
```

this will ensure the `invoke_file_runner` is executed only after connection established.

Comment: lol, seems i can accept my own answer, but where is my points? :)

Comment: Also, you could use **once** event listener. `output.addEventListener("open", /*func*/, { once: true})`.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwLkdksiClE